# How to clear inbetween webpages while moving from nth page to 1st page in HTML or JS

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, swipeview

I'm new to web programming. I'm working on PhoneGap android app. In that create a page from that i moving to many pages by swiping right side.

**Problem:** Suppose if i moved to nth page from that if i press home button, i need to clear inbetween page history and home page should get to shown.

How to do that using html or JS?

**EDIT:**

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: window.history.clear might work

Comment: no its not working, says "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<History> has no method 'clear'"

Comment: maybe you can play with window.length, if it's > some number go to home page...

Comment: its going to home page but after that if i press back button its going to the last page.....

Comment: well, that's the nature of history.back,
but you can use e.prevendefault() jquery function, if you are coming from certain pages and direct to the home page or wherever you want.

Comment: e.prevendefault() where i need to write? in homepage BackButton key press event?

Comment: are you using jquery mobile for paging?

Comment: Yes... I'm using jquery mobile.

Comment: Facing another problem, check the code I added in the question. I added it in the home page ondevice ready function. home page works fine but all other pages back button is not working.

Comment: try the one below, you can actually customize, that above will stop it all together

Answer (score 1):

ok, experimental but can be a solution for you

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
if ( typeof data.toPage === "object" ) {


                    var text = data.toPage.attr('id');

                    if(text =="your page name") {

                        $.mobile.changePage("#homepage", { transition: "none", reverse : true } );
                        e.preventDefault();

                    }
}
```

basically you are saying, hey, if I am coming from "your page name" don't do the default "going back" but go to home page

Comment: I tried your code. Redirect to home page occur but history still is there. From home page if i press back button its gong to last opened page....

Comment: Even if i add empty addEventListener for back button , in all pages back button is not working.

Comment: do you already have something like this for the back button?


$("backbutton").live("tap",function() {
            

            if (typeof (navigator.app) !== "undefined") {
                clog("navigator.app.backHistory();");

                if (lastAction !== "" || lastAction !== "undefined") {
                    //lastAction();
                    //return;
                }


                navigator.app.backHistory();
            } else {
                
                window.history.back();
            }
            return false;
        });

Comment: i dont have? what it ll do? //lasAction(); is  commented? I used this code but getting following error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' ". I'm using jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js and jquery-2.0.3.min.js.